# React - How to implement scrollbar while using "typing animation" for rendering messages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, scroll

I am building a Chat application and I have messages. For each received message from the server, to render I am using the `react-type-animation` npm package. I have implemented the scrollbar like this but this works when animation gets completed. I want to scroll while the animation is also in progress instead of completion.

```
const rootRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (rootRef?.current?._container) {
      rootRef.current._container.scrollTop =
        rootRef.current._container.scrollHeight;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [messages, scrollToBottom]);

    <Scrollbar options={{ suppressScrollX: true }} ref={rootRef} {...other}>
      <Box sx={{}}>
        {messages.map((message, index) => {
          return (
            <ChatMessage props... />
          );
        })}
      </Box>
    </Scrollbar>
```

And ChatMessage component looks like this:

```
const ChatMessage: FC<ChatMessageProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    loader,
    body,
    threadKey,
    thread,
    ...other
  } = props;


  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        py: 2,
      }}
      {...other}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          maxWidth: 1100,
          alignItems: 'center',
          width: '100%',
        }}
      >
            <Box sx={{ mt: 0, ml: 1 }}>
                <Typography
                  color="inherit"
                  variant="body1"
                  sx={{
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    fontWeight: 400,
                  }}
                >
                    <TypeAnimation
                      sequence={[
                        body?.response,  //Here message getting printed with animation
                      ]}
                      speed={75}
                      wrapper="span"
                      cursor={false}
                      style={{
                        fontSize: '1em',
                        display: 'inline-block',
                      }}
                    />
                </Typography>
            </Box>
          </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I tried adding a scrollbar but was unable to achieve it while an animation is in progress.

Comment: Important to note that the React-type-animation library utilises memoisation, a lot of functionality you would expect to work regarding react rendering does not happen. It is usually best to keep this library for relatively static instances and try implementing something else in the mean time